# _Pragma("omp parallel for") causes internal error in Visual compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I currently wonder why I get an compiler error in Visual.
I tested my code with Clang and GCC and it works without issues.
However, on Windows I seem to get an error or compiler crash.

[image]

Using #pragma seems to compile, but both expressions should be equal.

```
#define paral_prog_decl \
    _Pragma("omp parallel for") 

paral_prog_decl
    for(size_t i = 0; i < _raw.size(); i++) {
```

Comment: An internal compiler error is always a bug in the compiler. You should report this to Microsoft. With that said why are you using this macro?

Comment: Actually I wanted to save some code and add some code to the macro for loop progress which I didn't want to see in the loop code. 
So in the prog_decl would be declations and in the loop, I call another macro which is spawning output and calling an atomic.

Comment: You may want to see if `#pragma omp parallel for` causes the Microsoft bug in your code as well.

Comment: No only the _Pragma, #pragma and __pragma work again but is not standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you could refer to the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<omp.h>
#define paral_prog_decl \
    _Pragma("\"omp parallel for\"")

int main() {

    paral_prog_decl(x)
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

            printf("this is No.%d Thread ,i=%d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), i);
        }

    return 0;

}
```

Because Microsoft's directive is spelled slightly differently and, more annoyingly, doesn't want quotes surrounding the argument to the operator. I guess it that this instruction `omp parallel for` needs to be expressed in the form of a string. So, quotation marks and back-slashes should be escaped.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the correct solution--under Visual Studio 2022, I get a `warning C4081: expected 'identifier'; found 'string'`. It's best to use `__pragma` until Microsoft fixes this; apparently a fix is [on the way](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/using-c11s-pragma-with-openmp-directives-crashes-c/1590628).

Answer (score 2):

This is still an issue in Visual Studio 2022 and has an [official Developer Community thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/using-c11s-pragma-with-openmp-directives-crashes-c/1590628) on how using `_Pragma` with OpenMP in MSVC causes an internal compiler error. It's best to use Microsoft's `__pragma` here and use conditional compilation if you want to be cross-platform.

I faced this same issue today and my method to "abstract" this out was something like this:

```cpp
// per OpenMP standard, _OPENMP defined when compiling with OpenMP
#ifdef _OPENMP
#ifdef _MSC_VER
// must use MSVC __pragma here instead of _Pragma otherwise you get an internal
// compiler error. still an issue in Visual Studio 2022
#define PDDCP_OMP_PARALLEL_FOR __pragma(omp parallel for)
// any other standards-compliant C99/C++11 compiler
#else
#define PDDCP_OMP_PARALLEL_FOR _Pragma("omp parallel for")
#endif  // _MSC_VER
// no OpenMP support
#else
#define PDDCP_OMP_PARALLEL_FOR
#endif  // _OPENMP
```

Having `PDDCP_OMP_PARALLEL_FOR` always defined means you can also avoid warnings (depends on your compiler warning level) if you haven't enabled OpenMP/your compiler doesn't support OpenMP pragmas, so all OpenMP parallel loops can just be something like

```cpp
PDDCP_OMP_PARALLEL_FOR
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
  /* do something */;
```